# (Node.js child process) Spawning explorer, with /select option, does not work with spaces in path

Tags: node.js, windows, child-process, explorer

I'm writing a Node script that performs a "Reveal file in explorer" function. My code boils down to this:

```js
const {spawn} = require('child_process');

// This works (it opens C:/path/to/file and highlights the file named "WithoutSpaces"
spawn('explorer', ["C:\\path\\to\\file\\WithoutSpaces,", "/select"]);

// However, this does not work. It defaults to opening a file explorer window with my Documents folder.
spawn('explorer', ["C:\\this path\\has spaces,", "/select"]
spawn('explorer', ["C:\\this path\\has spaces\\file.txt,", "/select"]

// Strangely, spaces DO work if I'm not doing the /select option:
spawn('explorer', ["C:\\this path\\has spaces,", "/select"]
```

Strangely, when I use the /select argument to select a file, it only works when the path does not include any spaces. If the path does have spaces, then it defaults to the Documents folder.

Is there any way around this? Perhaps a way to encode a space with a backslash? Or maybe some other special arguments to the `explorer` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the windows-specific `windowsVerbatimArguments: true` option, listed in [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) for both `exec` and `spawn`, but easy to miss. Crucially, this is set to **false** by default, which is the opposite of what you want.

The following works just fine:

```
const path = require("path");
const {exec, spawn} = require("child_process");

spawn(`explorer`, [
  `/select,"${path.join(`C:`, `Program Files (x86)`, `Common Files`)}"`
], { windowsVerbatimArguments: true });
```